# MomentJS how to get formatted, but not localised representation?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I'm using MomentJS v2.8.4, and I'm trying to get formatted date like "31/12/2015"

`myDate.format('DD/MM/YYYY')` works fine until I set some "less English :)"  localisation, e.g. Arabic. Then I get something like this `١٠/٠١/٢٠١٥`, which is nice for the user, not so nice for API.

From MomentJS source code

```
format : function (inputString) {
    var output = formatMoment(this, inputString || moment.defaultFormat);
    // here I get correct "31/12/2015" format
    return this.localeData().postformat(output); // this will return localized version
},
```

formatMoment function is not publicly exported...

Can you please suggest correct solution for this?

Comment: Leave the localisation set to English, or perhaps there is some reason you want to use localisation?

Comment: Share some more of your code rather than a snippet from the momentjs library.

Comment: What solution did you end up choosing?

Answer (score 1):

You could save the current `locale()` setting in a variable (i.e save the user's setting) and then explicitly set the `locale` value so that you can get your date format correct for your API call, then set the `locale` value back to the saved value.

Something like:

```
var userLocaleSetting = moment.locale();
moment.locale('en');
var myFormattedDate = myDate.format('DD/MM/YYYY');
moment.locale( userLocaleSetting );
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution may be to return an object with the api and user formatted date.

```
format : function (inputString) {
    var api = formatMoment(this, inputString || moment.defaultFormat);
    // here I get correct "31/12/2015" format
    var user = this.localeData().postformat(api); // this will return localized version

   return {api: api, user: user};
},
```

Comment: That would work, but I do not want to fork and edit api of such known library as momentjs